# Editing Plot Output from gtrendsR

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

```
library(gtrendsR)
library(ggplot2)
usr <- "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
psw <- "XXXXX"
gconnect(usr, psw) 
climate_trend <- gtrends(c("climate", "cop21", "global warming"), res="week")

plot(climate_trend, main="whatttt", xlab="x")
```

Using plot editing options such as `main=` or `xlab=` do not create changes in the plot output, despite not receiving errors. I have thought about using `ggplot2` in conjunction with `gtrendsR` but that would require me converting the `list` data into an `data.frame` which I have had trouble with.

I appreciate any input on editing the axis of the plot output using `gtrendsR`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data frame you are probably interested in is just the `climate_trend$trend` element. Here is what I did to get a `ggplot2` graph:

```
library(gtrendsR)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

usr <- "xxxx@gmail.com"   # any gmail address and pw will do here
psw <- "xxxxx"
gconnect(usr, psw) 
climate_trend <- gtrends(c("climate", "cop21", "global warming"), res="week")

# plot(climate_trend$trend, main="whatttt")

# now for ggplot 2
tdf <- climate_trend$trend
mdf <- melt(tdf,id.vars=c("start","end"))
ggplot(data=mdf,aes(x=start,y=value,color=variable)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_point() +
  labs(title="Whatttt")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much man. I was searching for a long time yesterday to find the solution you have posted. Cheers!

Comment: My pleasure. It is an interesting data set too. Didn't know google published that.